# ¿Cómo saber hacia donde se dirige el touch con el evento touchmove en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eventos, touch

Tengo este fragmento de código:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var box = document.querySelector('canvas');
    box.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        console.log('move');
        console.log(e);
    })
}
</script>

<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

pero quiero una forma de saber hacia qué lado está dirigido el touch. Como está al presionar los botones con flechas:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.onkeydown = function (e) {
        console.log(e.key)
    };
}
```

Como le hago?

Comment: Relacionada (quizá duplicada): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436412/mejorar-c%c3%b3digo-de-firma-a-mano-alzada-a%c3%b1adiendo-soporte-para-dispositivos-m%c3%b3vile

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas guardar la posición de los eventos previos para obtener vectores: Si la posición actual es (18,10) y la anterior era (5,5), puedes calcular cuánto se ha movido (el módulo del vector) y en que dirección o ángulo)

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let previousTouch={x:0,y:0};
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    console.log(`moved from (${previousTouch.x},${previousTouch.y}) to (${touch.clientX},${touch.clientY})`);
    previousTouch.x=touch.clientX;
    previousTouch.y=touch.clientY;
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```