# CSS & JS: ¿Se podria activar un codigo JavaScript desde CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

A ver, me explico: Me gustaria crear un detector de cuando el cursor toca un elemento, pero el `.onmousemove()` es muy impreciso y quiero algo mas rapido, y se me ocurria usar el `:hover` de CSS, pero no se como (si es que se puede) conectar codigo JavaScript al activarse el `:hover` ¿Hay alguna forma?

Por ejemplo:

```
#elemento {
    /* ejecutarcodigojs */ 
}
```

¿Se podria llegar a hacer? O cualquier alternativa mas precisa al `.onmousemove()` me sirve tambien

Gracias.

Comment: Si estas usando jquery utiliza el .hover() que se ejecuta al momento de hacer hover a un elemento.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia pero no lo estoy usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no se puede, pero el mismo evento que aplica un estilo CSS sobre un elemento, se puede escuchar para ejecutar javascript. El nombre cambia, mientras en CSS es `hover`, en javascript el evento se llama `mouseover`:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseover', () => console.log('Ratón sobre el div'))
```

```css
div#hover {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
div:hover {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover"> Pon el ratón encima </div>
```

Comment: Entiendo pero no se si tiene que ver, pero estoy usando la propiedad cursor: none; y no es totalmente preciso, si paso muy rapido el cursor no pasa nada (hice que cuando se pase el cursor muestre un alert(), estoy haciendo un juego, por eso necesito mucha precision)

Comment: Si mueves demasiado rápido el cursor es posible que entre dos refrescos de pantalla el cursor haya cruzado todo el elemento y, por tanto, no se registre que en algún momento haya estado encima de dicho elemento. En ese caso tendrías que interpolar las coordenadas y comprobar si ha debido pasar por encima

Comment: Gracias por la información, y si no es mucho pedir, ¿Cómo haría eso? ¿algún tutorial o código?

Comment: Quizá esta otra pregunta/respuesta te ayude, aquí se calculan las posiciones por las que debe haber pasado el cursor para "suavizar" las líneas trazadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436412/mejorar-c%c3%b3digo-de-firma-a-mano-alzada-a%c3%b1adiendo-soporte-para-dispositivos-m%c3%b3vile

Comment: Muchas gracias :D